# XmlException: Multiple document element was detected

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading a XML file in a very simple way:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(dataPath);

while(reader.Read()){ 
    switch (reader.Name){
        case "language":
            Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
            break;
        case "file":
            Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
            break;
        case "arg":
            Debug.Log(reader.ReadString());
            break;
    }
```

}

Where my xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <config>
       <language>EN-US</language>
       <file>\File\Doc\sample.txt</file>
</config>
 <data>
       <arg>LKR</language>
</dara>
```

My first problem is this:

```
XmlException: Multiple document element was detected. file:///C:/prj/as/sample.xml Line 7, position 2.
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadStartTag ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.ReadContent ()
Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read ()
System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read ()
LectorXML.Start () (at as/sampleXML.cs:17)
```

And second, my output is language and file, but NO arg. Maybe because is a different node? How can i fix this?

Comment: Mono is at .NET 2.0, right? Then you shouldn't use `new XmlTextReader()`. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead. And you would be better off using `XmlDocument` instead, unless your document is too large to fit into memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have a single node element at the root of your document. You have a `<config>` and a `<data>`. Wrap them in a single document element:

```
<document>
  <config>
    <language>EN-US</language>
    <file>\File\Doc\sample.txt</file>
  </config>
  <data>
    <arg>LKR</arg>
  </data>
</document>
```

Comment: You XML also has </language> after your <arg>. I fixed that too.